# Scala not returning correct values

Tags: scala

So I was trying to run this code but when I try to print LineSegment it doesn't display correctly.

```
println(aLineSegment1.makeString(aLineSegment1))
```

gives `>LineSegment@77c2bc0d`

Any idea how to fix this?

```
class Point(x: Int, y: Int) {

    def xCoord = x
    def yCoord = y  

    def makeString(m: Point) = 
        "Point" + "(" + x + "," + y + ")"  
}
```

```
class LineSegment(x: Point, y: Point) { 

    def startSeg = x
    def endSeg = y

    def makeString(m: LineSegment) = 
        "LineSegment" + "(" + x + "," + y + ")"
}
```

```
object Mp5  {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val aLine1 = new Point(1, 2)
        val aLine2 = new Point(5, 4)
        val aLineSegment1 = new LineSegment(aLine1, aLine2)
        val aLineSegment2 = new LineSegment(new Point(-3, 5), new Point(8, -1))

        println(aLine1.makeString(aLine1))
        println(aLine2.makeString(aLine2))
        println(aLineSegment1.makeString(aLineSegment1)) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the `Point`'s `makeString()` methods from your `LineSegment.makeString()` method. You could do so by making the following change:

```
def makeString(m: LineSegment) = 
    "LineSegment" + "(" + x.makeString(x) + "," + y.makeString(y) + ")"
```

However, in Java/Scala, it's conventional to override the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method for object-to-string conversion. If you would do that, the conversion would be invoked automatically, without having to call the method yourself.

```
class Point(x: Int, y: Int) {
    def xCoord = x
    def yCoord = y  

    override def toString = "Point" + "(" + x + "," + y + ")" 
}

class LineSegment(x: Point, y: Point) {
    def startSeg = x
    def endSeg = y

    override def toString = "LineSegment" + "(" + x + "," + y + ")"
}

object Mp5  {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val aLine1 = new Point(1, 2)
        val aLine2 = new Point(5, 4)
        val aLineSegment1 = new LineSegment(aLine1, aLine2)

        println(aLineSegment1)
        // Prints out: LineSegment(Point(1,2),Point(5,4))
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Is there anyway to print without having to define a makeString method?

Comment: @RenzFitzgeraldIban You could use a scala [case class](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107), it will autogenerate the `toString()` method for you behind the scenes.